# Analytic number theory books between 1909 and 1957?

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, math-history

What are some general graduate-level textbooks in analytic number theory between Landau's Primzahlen (1909) and Prachar's Primzahlverteilung (1957)?

Comment: This sounds like a 20 to 30 minute task in a university library. Just scan over the lists of references in the back of analytic number theory texts and make your own list according to your specifications. In the U.S., where the Library of Congress classification system is used in nearly all universities, the books will be shelved in (or very close to) QA 241. Or search library catalogs online via "book call number" starting with QA 241, although you won't be able to look at the books' lists of references this way.

Comment: The point is that there seems to be a gap! I will soon look through two *German* university libraries - perhaps I'll have some luck.

Comment: Titchmarsh's Theory of the Riemann Zeta Function is not quite what I would call general (though it comes close).

Comment: Ditto for Vinogradov's Method of trigonometric sums. it's strange - there are quite a few books on algebraic number theory from that period!

Comment: I've just found a reference to a book by Estermann - will look.

Comment: On the class number formula there is Hecke's lectures on the theory of algebraic numbers (the German edition would be 1923) what do you search for exactly

Comment: Yes, there are tons of textbooks on alg num th, and you are right that the two subdomains intersect (notably in exactly the way you mention). What I wonder is whether there is really a (barely believable) 48-year-gap. How could that be the case?

Comment: Did you look at Titchmarsh [original 1930 text](https://archive.org/details/zetafunctionofri032076mbp/page/n7) it suggests there is a lot of work needed to clean up the research publications and making it accessible. What content did you find in Landau

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of analytic number theory even in Landau's other books on algebraic number theory. A standard reference before Landau is Paul
Bachmann's book on analytic number theory from the 1890s. Then there are
several lecture notes that Siegel made available (Lectures on analytic number theory, and several on "Funktionentheorie") the university library of 
Göttingen used to make them available, and almost all of Siegel's lectures 
are fantastic). In addition, there are

1. Ingham, The distribution of prime numbers, 1932
2. Titchmarsh, The theory of the Riemann zeta-function, 1951
3. Estermann, Introduction to modern prime number theory, 1952.

Other than that I haven't found anything (except that Suetuna wrote a book on analytic number theory in Japanese in 1950).